# Memory usage/footprint potential issue(s)

Tags: perl

So, I need to store about 8 GB of information to iterate over/use for computations;  however,  I won't need to modify any of it. Can I do this inside of my perl script or will I run out of memory (I have 8 GB of RAM). If not, can I store the information in files instead?  Do I need to put everything in a database (NB: I have no database experience and would like to avoid them for now unless I absolutely can't do it in any other fashion)? For each computation,  I will need to iterate over a subset of around 1 GB of "sentences." For each of those "sentences,"  I'll need to derive a quantity and then compare all of those quantities to get the top X%.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: No one else will be using this data.  Only one program will need access to the data. Security is not an issue,  but speed is. I'm going to use forking or threading for parallellization. I can use Windows  or Linux.

Comment: Is this subset of sentences a contiguous sequence, or is it a random selection of the source data? And will all threads be working with the same subset?

Comment: So, I basically have a ton of groups of related sentences. I need to go over each of these groups and compute quantities for each sentence.  Once I have all of those values,  I need to take the top X%. I was going to set up different threads/processes to handle the computations for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good application for [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html), which allows a file to be used as an array.

Per the documentation:

> The file is not loaded into memory, so this will work even for gigantic files.

Comment: Great, that seems like exactly what I need in terms of document storage;  however,  I'm still going to need to compute similarities for millions of lines across different files, compare them all and take the top X%. Any suggestions for how to do this? I guess I could write all the quantities to a file with some description of where each quantity came from, but then I need to sort them and take that top X% and do something with that subset.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If speed is an issue then `Tie::File` may be a problem. I suggest you run with this solution and see if it's quick enough for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "this solution?" If you're referring to trying Tie:File, please refer to my comment above.  I'm still confused as to how I'd deal with the latter part of that comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant you should try `Tie::File` and see if it is fast enough for your purpose. I'm still unclear about your problem. What are these *quantitities* you are comparing? If each is a single numerical value then you can just store them in a Perl array and sort them there. This is going a off topic rather, and I suggest you should write a new question describing the problem in detail.